LDAP - 389ds - FluentD - Filter plugin - type record_transformer - can it have more than one <record> stanza entries?
Can FluentD 1.16.3/+ have more than one record entries inside filter plugin for type record_transformer?
I have the following configuration, but it seems like it's keeping ONLY the last record entry.
  <filter authentication>
    @type record_transformer
    enable_ruby
    remove_keys log
    <record>
      message ${record["log"]}
      audit.category Login
      audit.event ${if record["log"].include? "Invalid credentials"; 'Failed'; else; 'Successful' end;} Login
      audit.dashboards.authentication true
    </record>
    <record>
      message ${record["log"]}
      audit.category Anonymous_Login
      audit.event ${if record["log"].include? "Anonymous access not allowed"; 'LDAP Anonymous Access Attempted'; end;}
      audit.dashboards.authentication true
    </record>
    <record>
      message ${record["log"]}
      audit.category LDAP_Search
      audit.event ${if record["log"].include? "SRCH base="; 'LDAP Search Action'; end;}
      audit.dashboards.authentication true
    </record>
    <record>
      message ${record["log"]}
      audit.category LDAP_Search_Result
      audit.event ${if record["log"].include? "RESULT err="; 'LDAP Search Result'; end;}
      audit.dashboards.authentication true
    </record>
  </filter>

I tried to place all those if statements into a generic LOGIN category but then the elsif is not helping in my case, as if one of the elsif conditions turns TRUE, the rest won't be checked.
  <filter authentication>
    @type record_transformer
    enable_ruby
    <record>
      message ${record["log"]}
      audit.category Login
      audit.event ${if record["log"].include? "Invalid credentials"; 'Failed Login'; elsif record["log"].include? "Anonymous access not allowed"; 'LDAP Anonymous Access Attempted'; elsif record["log"].include? "SRCH base="; 'LDAP Search Action'; elsif record["log"].include? "RESULT err="; 'LDAP Search Result'; end;} 
      audit.dashboards.authentication true
    </record>
    remove_keys log
  </filter>


Solved.
Had to set audit.category and audit.event fields using IF-THEN-ELSIF-ELSE statements.
Multiple <record> chunks didn't work as expected (if I wanted to keep them separate. Noticed, some of the records(log lines) were missing in ELK (viewed in Kibana UI > Discover > given time-window).
  <filter authentication>
    @type record_transformer
    enable_ruby
    <record>
      message ${record["log"]}
      audit.category ${if record["log"].include? "Invalid credentials"; 'Login'; elsif record["log"].include? "Anonymous access not allowed"; 'Anonymous Login'; elsif record["log"].include? "SRCH base="; 'LDAP Event'; elsif record["log"].include? "RESULT err="; 'LDAP Event'; end;}
      audit.event ${if record["log"].include? "Invalid credentials"; 'Failed Login'; elsif record["log"].include? "Anonymous access not allowed"; 'LDAP Anonymous Access Attempted'; elsif record["log"].include? "SRCH base="; 'LDAP Search Action'; elsif record["log"].include? "RESULT err="; 'LDAP Search Result'; end;} 
      audit.dashboards.authentication true
    </record>
    remove_keys log
  </filter>

